# Range of a function a

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I find the range of $a$ if I've been given a condition that $$a(x+y)\leq x^2+y^2+xy+1$$ where $x,y$ are  real variables I don't have any clue of how to start solving the problem.Any hint might work.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $$x+y=0$$ then we get $$0\le x^2+y^2+xy+1$$

If $$x+y>0$$ then we have $$a\le \frac{x^2+y^2+xy+1}{x+y}$$

If $$x+y<0$$ then we have $$a\geq \frac{x^2+y^2+xy+1}{x+y}$$

Comment: Sonnhard Graubner Sorry but I only know how to find range of numerator in the inequality expression you have mentioned.Im in 10th grade right now .so could you help a little bit more

Comment: You can solve your inequality for $x$ or $y$

Comment: I know how to solve inequalities by wave curve method and that's useful only when the expression is factorisable .

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

\begin{align*}
a(x+y) & \leq x^2+y^2+xy+1\\
2a(x+y)&\leq 2x^2+2y^2+2xy+2\\
2a(x+y)&\leq x^2+y^2+(x+y)^2+2\\
0&\leq (x-a)^2+(y-a)^2+(x+y)^2+2(1-a^2)\\
\end{align*}
If $1-a^2 \geq 0$, then the right hand side is always non-negative. So if $a \in [-1,1]$, then this inequality holds for all $x,y$.

Now see if you can handle the case when $1-a^2<0$. Can you find $x,y$ such that the inequality no longer holds?